# AngularJS module: this versus $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, this

I'm new to AngularJS. I would like to know what the difference is between
the following two code snippets:

I. Code that defines a controller using this:

```
var app = angular.module('greeting', []);
app.controller('HelloCtrl', function() {
  this.name = 'Hello World';
});
```

II. Code that defines a controller using $scope:

```
var app = angular.module('greeting', []);
app.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'Hello World';
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two implementations are used differently in the view. The *this* syntax is used together with the *controller as* syntax, which essentially makes your controller your view model.

**controller as example**

*In Controller*

```
this.text = "Controller as example"
```

*In View*

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as controllerViewModel">
    {{controllerViewModel.text}}
</div>
```

**Scope equivalent**

*In Controller*

```
$scope.text = "Scope example";
```

*In View*

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{text}}</div>
```

**Here are some usefull links regarding the subject**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

https://thinkster.io/egghead/experimental-controller-as-syntax/

Answer (score 1):

'this' is referring to the instance of your HelloCtrl...
$scope is an entirely different object that's already got state and is managed through angular